# add Click listener method in RecyclerView Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add `ClickListeners` in `RecyclerView` I  have 4 pictures in it means 4 items and I want that every item clicks move to different activity

**Adapter_Workout.java**

```
public class Adapter_Workout extends RecyclerView.Adapter<View_Holder_Workout> {
    
    ArrayList<Model_Class_Workout> data_adapter_dashboard_workout;
    
        public Adapter_Workout(ArrayList<Model_Class_Workout> data)
        {
            this.data_adapter_dashboard_workout = data;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View_Holder_Workout onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dashboard_workout_,parent,false);
            return  new View_Holder_Workout(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull View_Holder_Workout holder, int position)
        {   holder.img_view_holder_dashoboard_workout.setImageResource(data_adapter_dashboard_workout.get(position).getImg_model_class_workout());
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data_adapter_dashboard_workout.size();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add click in adapter from two ways:

1. In onBindViewHolder
2. In ViewHolder Class

OnBindViewHolder click example : --
public class Adapter_Workout extends RecyclerView.Adapter<View_Holder_Workout> {

```
    ArrayList<Model_Class_Workout> data_adapter_dashboard_workout;
    
        public Adapter_Workout(ArrayList<Model_Class_Workout> data)
        {
            this.data_adapter_dashboard_workout = data;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View_Holder_Workout onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dashboard_workout_,parent,false);
            return  new View_Holder_Workout(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull View_Holder_Workout holder, int position)
        {   holder.img_view_holder_dashoboard_workout.setImageResource(data_adapter_dashboard_workout.get(position).getImg_model_class_workout());

    holder.img_view_holder_dashoboard_workout.setOnClickListener {
                   val intent = Intent(context,ABC.class)
                   context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data_adapter_dashboard_workout.size();
        }
    }
```

ViewHolder Click example:---

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ViewHolder(View item) {

        super(item);
        item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("RecyclerView", "onClick：" + getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: 1 want to add 4 intents

Comment: You can use switch case and use getAdapterPosition() for 4 different intents